# Clear login session after logging out in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to clear login session using AngularJS code.

```
  $scope.clearLogin = function () {
        delete $window.sessionStorage;
        window.localStorage.clear();
        $window.location.href = 'index.html';
  };
```

This is redirecting me to index page but when I click on back button I am getting into the application and the session is still available.

How to clear session restricting the user to log into the application after logging out?

Comment: try this: sessionStorage.clear()

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be  **`$window`**

```
 $scope.clearLogin = function () {
        delete $window.sessionStorage;
        $window.localStorage.clear();
        $window.location.href = 'index.html';
  };
```